# MySql sort query with multiple fields

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sorting

I have two tables "activity_stats" & "activity_stats_values"

```
activity_stats table
# id, activity_id, kyf_id, kyf_sort
618      84          5       1
619      84          6       2
638      84          4       3 

activity_stats_values table
# id, activity_id, player_id, kyf_id, value
2563    84          46          5       45
2564    84          46          6       60
2587    84          47          5       10
2588    84          47          6       25
2589    84          49          5       10
2590    84          49          6       40
2591    84          48          5       30
2592    84          48          6       15
2594    84          46          4       NULL
2595    84          47          4       80
2596    84          48          4       NULL
2597    84          49          4       NULL
```

**Requirement**

---

players should be sorted by values in descending order. Meaning the player with highest value of first keyfigure(kyf_id , kyf_id position based on field "kyf_sort" of table "activity_stats") should be on top (then second key figure, then third key figure).

Expected output

```
# id, activity_id, player_id, kyf_id, value  kyf_sort
 2563   84          46          5       45      1
 2564   84          46          6       60      2
 2594   84          46          4       NULL    3

 2591   84          48          5       30      1
 2592   84          48          6       15      2
 2596   84          48          4       NULL    3

 2589   84          49          5       10      1
 2590   84          49          6       40      2
 2597   84          49          4       NULL    3

 2587   84          47          5       10      1
 2588   84          47          6       25      2
 2595   84          47          4       80      3
```

OR playes ids in order [46,48,49,47]

```
I tried the following query
```

---

```
SELECT    ac_st_v.activity_id,ac_st_v.player_id,ac_st_v.value,ac_st.kyf_id,ac_st.kyf_sort,pl.first_name ,
(select max(value)  
 from activity_stats_values 
  where activity_id=ac_st_v.activity_id 
     and kyf_id=ac_st.kyf_id 
 group by activity_id) as m_value
FROM teamplayer.activity_stats_values as ac_st_v
 JOIN teamplayer.activity_stats as ac_st
  ON ac_st_v.activity_id=ac_st.activity_id 
   AND  ac_st_v.kyf_id=ac_st.kyf_id
 JOIN teamplayer.players as pl
  ON ac_st_v.player_id=pl.id
where ac_st_v.activity_id= 84  
order by  ac_st_v.player_id,ac_st.kyf_sort,m_value
```

Is there any way to sort the values like this?

Comment: On what basis you need the **players ids in order [47,48,49,47]**?

Comment: @viki888  :  player with highest value of first kyf_id ( kyf_id position based on field "kyf_sort" of table "activity_stats") should be on top,.
if two players match the same value based on first kyf_id the  we choose 2nd kyf_id values for that players

Comment: @viki888  expected players id order is **[46,48,49,47]**